# Laravel Many to Many Polymorphic Query Returns NULL

Tags: php, laravel, polymorphism, eloquent

I've been working on this for hours and can't figure out the answer to a simple question. I can't seem to retrieve my polymorphic many to many via morphedByMany. Relevant code below:

Tag Model snippet:

```
class Tag extends Eloquent
{
   protected $table = 'tags';

   public function posts()
   {
       return $this->morphedByMany('Post', 'taggable');
   }
```

Post Model snippet:

```
class Post extends Eloquent
{
   protected $table = 'posts';

   public $incrementing = false;

   public function tags()
   {
       return $this->morphToMany('Tag', 'taggable');
   }
```

The offending line. Even though there are tags for the post and posts for the tags which I can see in the database, this line returns NULL no matter what I tweak:

```
$posts = Tag::find(1)->posts;
```

Schemas (note I've also tried this without indexing those fields, and also with having a foreign key on tag_id):

```
Schema::create('taggables', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('taggable_type')->index();
    $table->bigInteger('taggable_id')->index();
    $table->integer('tag_id')->unsigned()->index();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

If you need any other code let me know. I'm at the end of my rope.

Comment: Have you tried `Tag::find(1)->posts()->get();`?

Comment: This yields:

Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::posts()

Comment: Oh wow I figured it out I had copied and pasted some model text, which led to my Flag model also being called Tag. Given that Flag.php is first in alphabetical order, I'm assuming that was referenced first and had no polymorphic relations. Embarrassing.

Is it SO etiquette to delete this now since it's probably not of much help haha?